# create a Python dictionary where for each key has a list as the value

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary below with the results to like;

```
{'1':1,'2':2,'3':3,'4':4,'5':5,'6':6,'7'}
```

```
list1 = ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7')
counter = 0
for x in list1:
    counter =  counter+1
    d = {
        x:counter
    }
```

but the results I am getting are: `{'7': 7}`

Comment: Your desired result doesn't have a list as the value of each key, it has a number as the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dict comprehension:

```py
d = {x: int(x) for x in list1}
```

or

```py
d = {x: i+1 for i, x in enumerate(list1)}
```

If you want to still have the loop, try:

```py
list1 = ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7')
counter = 0
for x in list1:
    counter =  counter+1
    d[x] = counter
```

or `d.update({x: counter})` instead of `d[x] = counter`.

Answer (score 0):

You are reassigning `d` on every iteration.

Either way, you can do this with a dictionary comprehension and `enumerate`:

```
>>> list1 = ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7')
>>> d = {x: counter for counter, x in enumerate(list1, 1)}
{'1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict1 = { x: int(x) for x in list1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a new dict each time

Start one and add to it

```py
d = {}
for foo in bar:
    d[foo] = baz
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you erase the variable `d` at each iteration.

You want to add the new key and value to an already existing dictionary (created empty: `d = {}`), with `d[x] = counter`.